# Parse for Android can't pin List of subclass to cache

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

As indicated by http://blog.parse.com/2013/05/30/parse-on-android-just-got-classier/ Parse now supports subclassing of ParseObject. My issue arrises when I try to "pin" my retrieved `List` of `Post` objects from my query to the cache.

`Post` is a subclass of `ParseObject`

```
   ParseQuery<Post> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Post.class);
    query.orderByDescending("updatedAt");

    // Gets all posts from Parse.
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Post>() {
        @Override
        public void done(final List<Post> posts, ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                // There was an error or the network wasn't available.
                return;
            }

            // Nothing to update.
            if (posts.size() == 0) {
                return;
            }

            // Add the latest Posts from this query to the local cache.
            Post.pinAllInBackground(POST_CACHE_LABEL, posts);
            updateMapFromCache();
        }
    });
```

`ParseObject.pinAllInBackground()` only accepts `List<ParseObject>` not `List<?>` which is now creating an issue for me. Does anyone have a solution to this besides iterating through `List<Post>` and pinning them individually?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

*This is not a answer, but I didn't have enough repo to comment.*

I am having this same problem, once a object of subclass of PraseObject is stored in local data store.
I am able to retrieve it while the application is running, once application is restarted, what I get from a query similar to above is a list of ParseObject's and not a list of my custom object.
For now what I did is, created a custom parser to recreate a object of my custom implementation. But this defeats the purpose of what is indicated in "http://blog.parse.com/2013/05/30/parse-on-android-just-got-classier/".

Comment: I've discovered that you need to call `ParseObject.registerSubclass(Class<? extends ParseObject>)` *before* you call `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(Context)` to get pinned subclass objects to have the correct types.