# Parse.com Android pinAllInBackground only pins 1

Tags: java, android, caching, parse-platform, pinning

Im having a problem, when i try to pin a list of objects in the background. After getting the list again I only get 1 item.

The output is :

splash acticvity, found 100 first "somename"

and

found in pin 1 first "somename"

So it only stores and gives back the first item of the list. WHY ?!
Thanks in advance!

```
    ParseQuery<Studio> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Studio.class);
    query.whereWithinKilometers("geolocation", new ParseGeoPoint(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), defaultDistance);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Studio>() {

        public void done(List<Studio> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                Log.e(Constants.TAG, "splash acticvity, found " + objects.size() 
                      + " first " + objects.get(0).getDisplayname()); // 100

                ParseObject.pinAllInBackground("closestStudios", objects, 
                  new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {

                            ParseQuery<Studio> testQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(Studio.class);
                            testQuery.fromPin("closestStudios");
                            testQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Studio>() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(List<Studio> studios, ParseException e) {
                                    Log.e(Constants.TAG, "found in pin " + studios.size() + " first " + studios.get(0).getDisplayname());
                                }
                            });

                            showList();
                        }
                    }

                });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Studio.class is a custom type extending ParseObject.

Comment: I just unregistered my ParseObject Subclass (Studio) and now use ParseObject directly. With that it works, but subclassing is quite useful. Is there a way to have subclassing and pinning of objects ?

Comment: Try iterating through the objects list and pinning them individually, object.pin("Name"). I am subclassing and pinning this way and its working fine.

Comment: This would change my logic and I would need to store the names somewhere in order to get them back somewhere else. Or can I store every object to the same pin and it will end up as a list? I guess not...

Comment: As far as i understand, even if you pin the list, it will pin individual objects only and the name specified is the group name. To get the objects back you will use query.fromPin("GroupName"). I dont know why its not working for the list, couldnt find anything on that. I think others are also facing similar problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962324/parse-for-android-cant-pin-list-of-subclass-to-cache

Comment: Try using pinAll() too once...